# How can I capture specific characters before a delimiter using RegEx?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to create two regular expressions to capture the needed characters of a European license plate.

I'm using two RegEx at the moment

1. Capture the country

   - `(^[A-Z]{1,3}[\\s])`
2. Capture the district

   - `(([^\\s*-A-Z]{1,3}[*])|([^\\s*-A-Z]{1,3}[-])`)

Here are examples of licenseplates formats I have:

```
D HG-ABCDE : Country should be D, District should be HG
A S-FGHIJ  : Country should be A, District should be S 
D AC-KLMNO : Country should be D, District should be AC
A BR-PQRST : Country should be A, District should be BR
A RO*UVWXY : Country should be A, District should be RO
```

Once I get the needed information out of my Strings, I remove the information I don't need with java code, here's the code piece:

```
if (matcher.find()) {
        
        country_region = matcher.group(1);
        country_region = country_region.replace("*", "");
        country_region = country_region.replace("-", "");
        country_region = country_region.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");            

    }
```

Now that I have explained my topic, here's the problem I am having.
My **District RegEx** does not work as intended, it selects the wrong letters and that results in a wrong mapping from my side afterwards. I unfortunately could not find my error and here I am asking for help!

How may I rewrite my District RegEx to retrieve the letters **after the space separating the country from the district but before the delimiters * or - ?**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character class `[^\\s*-A-Z]` is a negated character class which matches any char except the listed. This part `\\s*-A` denotes a range from ASCII decimal number 42-65, and will also not match the `A` char.

If you would change it into `[\s*A-Z-]{1,3}` it would still match a space and a hyphen matching too much.

---

You could use 2 capture groups where the Country is in group 1 and the District is in group 2.

To match either `-` or `*` you can use a character class `[-*]`

```
^([A-Z]{1,3})\h+([A-Z]{1,3})[-*][A-Z]{5}$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `([A-Z]{1,3})` Capture 1-3 occurrences of A-Z in **group 1**
- `\h+` Match 1+ occurrences of a horizontal whitespace char
- `([A-Z]{1,3})` Capture 1-3 occurrences of A-Z in **group 2**
- `[-*][A-Z]{5}` Match either `-` or `*` and 5 occurrences of A-Z
- `$` End of string

In Java

```
String regex = "^([A-Z]{1,3})\\h+([A-Z]{1,3})[-*][A-Z]{5}$";
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qWRkUu/1)

Only capturing the first 2 groups without the chars at the end and starting with a word boundary:

```
\b([A-Z]{1,3})\h+([A-Z]{1,3})[-*]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VOILuh/1)

Comment: Thank you very much. In order to prevent having to rewrite my whole java part, how could I only capture the first group in one regex (country), and the second group (district) in another regex?

Comment: @Djabone Then this could be the first part `^([A-Z]{1,3}) ` and this could be the second part `\\h([A-Z]{1,3})[-*]`

Comment: Thank you, they work like a charm. Is there any syntax difference in rewriting those RegEx as Strings in java?

Comment: @Djabone In Java, you have to double escape the backslash.

Comment: Thanks! In some cases, it might also be that I have format such as those some Districts might look like LöN, or DüS - How may I confront that?

Comment: @Djabone In that case you can use this to match any kind of letter `^([A-Z]{1,3})\h*(\p{L}{1,3})[-*]?` https://regex101.com/r/5wJ5Wn/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237757/discussion-between-djabone-and-the-fourth-bird).